# Бинарная сериализация файла. BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, десериализация

У меня есть приложение клиент и сервер. Сервер отправляет файл по протоколу TCP, клиент принимает. Вот только после того как сервер отправил, клиент не может сделать десериализацию.
Вот функция отправки файл.

```
public string SendFileName = null;
public void SendData()
{
    // Состав отсылаемого универсального сообщения
    // 1. Заголовок о следующим объектом класса подробной информации дальнейших байтов
    // 2. Объект класса подробной информации о следующих байтах
    // 3. Байты непосредственно готовых к записи в файл или для чего-то иного.
    SendInfo si = new SendInfo();

    //  Если нет отсылаемого файла продолжать процедуру отправки нет смысла.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendFileName) == true) return;

    if (SendFileName != null)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(SendFileName);
        if (fi.Exists == true)
        {
            si.filesize = (int)fi.Length;
            si.filename = fi.Name;
        }
        fi = null;
    }

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, si);
    ms.Position = 0;
    byte[] infobuffer = new byte[ms.Length];
    int r = ms.Read(infobuffer, 0, infobuffer.Length);
    ms.Close();

    byte[] header = GetHeader(infobuffer.Length);
    byte[] total = new byte[header.Length + infobuffer.Length + si.filesize];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, total, 0, header.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(infobuffer, 0, total, header.Length, infobuffer.Length);

    // Если путь файла указан, добавим его содержимое в отправляемый массив байтов
    if (si.filesize > 0)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(SendFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        fs.Read(total, header.Length + infobuffer.Length, si.filesize);
        fs.Close();
        fs = null;
    }
    try
    {
        // Отправим данные подключенным клиентам
        NetworkStream ns = _tcpClient.tcpClient.GetStream();
        // Так как данный метод вызывается в отдельном потоке рациональней использовать синхронный метод отправки
        ns.Write(total, 0, total.Length);

        // Обнулим все ссылки на многобайтные объекты и попробуем очистить память
        header = null;
        infobuffer = null;
        total = null;
        SendFileName = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        // Подтверждение успешной отправки
        Parent.ShowReceiveMessage("Данные успешно отправлены!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }  
}
```

Вот функция принятия файла на Клиентской стороне:

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if (modeNetwork == Mode.indeterminately) return;

    TcpClientData myTcpClient = (TcpClientData)ar.AsyncState;

    try
    {
        NetworkStream ns = myTcpClient.tcpClient.GetStream();

        int r = ns.EndRead(ar);

        if (r > 0)
        {
            // Из главного заголовка получим размер массива байтов информационного объекта
            string header = Encoding.Default.GetString(myTcpClient.buffer);
            int leninfo = int.Parse(header);

            // Получим и десериализуем объект с подробной информацией о содержании получаемого сетевого пакета
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(leninfo);
            byte[] temp = new byte[leninfo];
            r = ns.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
            ms.Write(temp, 0, r);
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            ms.Position = 0;
            SendInfo sc = (SendInfo)bf.Deserialize(ms);
            ms.Close();

            if (sc.filesize > 0)
            {
                // Создадим файл на основе полученной информации и массива байтов следующих за объектом информации
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(sc.filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite, sc.filesize);
                do
                {
                    temp = new byte[global.MAXBUFFER];
                    r = ns.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);

                    // Записываем строго столько байтов сколько прочтено методом Read()
                    fs.Write(temp, 0, r);

                    // Как только получены все байты файла, останавливаем цикл,
                    // иначе он заблокируется в ожидании новых сетевых данных
                    if (fs.Length == sc.filesize)
                    {
                        fs.Close();
                        fs = null;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                while (r > 0);

                temp = null;
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }




            if (Receive != null)
                Receive(this, new ReceiveEventArgs(sc));

            myTcpClient.buffer = new byte[global.LENGTHHEADER];
            ns.BeginRead(myTcpClient.buffer, 0, myTcpClient.buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), myTcpClient);

        }
        else
        {
            DeleteClient(myTcpClient);

            // Событие клиент отключился
            if (Disconnected != null)
                Disconnected.BeginInvoke(this, "Клиент отключился!", null, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        DeleteClient(myTcpClient);


        // Событие клиент отключился
        if (Disconnected != null)
        {
            Disconnected.BeginInvoke(this, "Произошла ошибка во время обновления Базы Даных. Просьба повторить попытку.", null, null);
        }
        SoundError();

    }

}
```

Вот это класс, который есть и на Клиенте и на Сервере:

```
[Serializable]
class SendInfo
{

    public string message;

    public string filename;

    public int filesize;
}
```

Вот на этой строчке

```
SendInfo sc = (SendInfo)bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

и происходит ошибка, а именно пишет:

> {"Не удалось привести тип объекта \"SERVER.SendInfo\" к типу \"KLIENT.SendInfo\"."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Comment: И что вам не понятно из текста ошибки?

Comment: Не понятно? А то, что класс одинаковый, что в Клиенте, что в Сервере. А привести он не может. Как то это не нормально по-моему. Мне кажется каких то строчек в настройках не хватает

Comment: На сервере у Вас класс `SERVER.SendInfo` а на клиенте `KLIENT.SendInfo`. Это разные классы, даже если их определения совпадают.

Comment: Разве для сериализации это имеет значение? Ей бы чтобы классы были одного названия, да и поля. Подскажите пожалуйста, что тогда делать, третий день уже голову ломаю.

Comment: *Ей бы чтобы классы были одного названия, да и поля.* А можно ссылку на документацию, где Вы это прочли? *Подскажите пожалуйста, что тогда делать, третий день уже голову ломаю.* Удалить один из классов. P.S. Если Вы разделите строку `SendInfo sc = (SendInfo)bf.Deserialize(ms);` на `object o = bf.Deserialize(ms);` и `SendInfo sc = (SendInfo)o;`, то Вы увидите, что исключение возникает не в вызове `Deserialize`.

Comment: Ссылки нет, это я так понял тему. Значит плохо. Но ведь если удалю один из классов, ошибка будет. Он же у меня и в отправке и в получении используется.

Comment: Так ведь у Вас два одинаковых класса. Если один удалите, то второй у Вас останется. Им и пользуйтесь. Смысл в том, что для каждого типа сообщения у Вас должен быть один общий класс, а не один на клиенте, а другой на сервере.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77109/discussion-between--and-petseral).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из ошибки видно, что вы пытаетесь привести объект одного типа, к объекту другого типа. Даже в случае, если классы имеют одинаковые поля и одинаковое название, это все равно разные классы.

Существует два варианта решения проблемы:

- реализовать **explicit** оператор;
- вынесли сериализуемый класс в отдельную сборку (библиотека классов) и подключить ее для обоих проектов.

---

Ссылки по теме:

- [Ключевые слова преобразований: explicit](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit)
- [Двоичная сериализация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.120).aspx)